# ng-click with parameter not working inside dynamic template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the AngularUI bootstrap library in my project. In particular, I'm using the accordion and a custom template to display the accordion groups etc. On the template I have an ng-click event which seems to be working only when I don't have the parameter on it. Inside my  directive I have a scope variable that produces a unique identifier which I have included as a parameter on the ng-click event. What am I missing to get this working? I'm using Angular 1.0.8.

thanks in advance

!-- template

```
 <a callback="accordion_group_opened($index)" ng-click="callSubmit(currentRow)">
```

!-- scope variable incremented each time the directive is called

```
countRow = generateUnique.getNextIdStartingAtOne();
scope.currentRow = countRow;
```

Edit:

Added the compilation still not getting the value from the scope into my ng-click param. Any ideas on a work around?

```
   compile:function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var countRow = generateUnique.getNextIdStartingAtOne();
            scope.currentRow = countRow;
            return function(scope, element, attr) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    var fn = $parse(attr["ngClick"]);
                    element[0].on("click", function(event) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            fn(scope, {$event:event});
                        });
                    });
                })
            };
        }
```

Comment: How are you including the template. Most probably you would need to use `$compile` service to compile the template and bindings to work.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930392/how-to-use-a-model-property-as-variable-ng-click

Comment: I'm including template using the same method as bootstrap is using, but I've included it in a separate file which overrides the intial bootstrap version. It's working alright but I just can't pass the parameter with the ng-click function.